# ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE cannot read process output produced before process termination

Tags: c++, winapi

I've a simply process redirection routine in Win32. The problem here is that, if I put a Sleep between reads from the child process stdout, as soon as the process terminates while I sleep, I simply miss the last bytes from the pipe that outputs a ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE. It seems that , as soon as the child process terminates, it's pipes and associated handles are closed and anything pending discarded. The only solution seems to ReadFile from the pipe as fast as possible, but this is more than a problem for me due to the design of the software.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BOOL bSuccess;
    WCHAR szCmdLine[MAX_PATH];
    char chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD dwRead;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd2 = NULL;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2 = NULL;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr2; 
    STARTUPINFO si2;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi2;

    ZeroMemory( &si2, sizeof(si2) );
    si2.cb = sizeof(si2);
    ZeroMemory( &pi2, sizeof(pi2) );
    //create pipe
    saAttr2.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
    saAttr2.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
    saAttr2.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 
    assert(CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd2, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2, &saAttr2, 0));
    //create child process
    bSuccess = FALSE;
    memset(szCmdLine, 0, MAX_PATH);
    wsprintf(szCmdLine, L"c:\\myprocess.exe");
    ZeroMemory( &pi2, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );
    ZeroMemory( &si2, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
    si2.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
    si2.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2;
    si2.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2; // also add the pipe as stderr!
    si2.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    assert(CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdLine, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si2, &pi2));
    //read from pipe
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2);
    memset(chBuf, 0, BUFSIZE);
    for (;;) 
    { 
        DWORD dwRead = 0;
        DWORD bytes = 0;
        if (!PeekNamedPipe(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd2,NULL,NULL,NULL,&bytes,NULL)) {
            //printf("Peek named pipe failed!");
            break;
        }

        if (bytes != 0) {
            if (!ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd2, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL)) 
            {
                printf("EOF!!\n");
                break;

            }
            else {
                chBuf[dwRead] = 0;
                printf("%s", chBuf);
            }

        } else {
            Sleep(5000);
        }

    }
    while(1) {
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("Lopp!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any hint ? Is there a way to keep the process on hold, like it happens in POSIX, until its pipes are read ?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to do it explicitly, call FlushFileBuffers() before you terminate.

Comment: @HansPassant: that doesn't appear to be necessary.  I can't reproduce the problem, even by having the child process terminate itself rather than exiting cleanly.  Unless the child is actually calling DisconnectNamedPipe or something equally bizarre, I can't imagine what it could be doing to cause this.

Comment: @Leonardo: assuming the problem is indeed with the child process and can't be resolved, the best workaround is probably to not close `g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2`.  The catch is that this means ReadFile/PeekNamedPipe won't tell you when the child process has exited, so you'll have to check that separately.  That means using polling, which is inefficient (or asynchronous I/O, which is complicated) but if you can't find another solution it may be the only way forward.

Comment: I'm considering moving the read operation on another blocking thread, that way I can read as fast as possible....

Comment: That would still be a race condition, because the thread might not get scheduled in time.  It might work most of the time but wouldn't be reliable.

Comment: I may have a ready to run threads pool...so I don't see that as a problem honestly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for reference only, I would like to share my experience and how I solved the problem.
IT may be possible that there's something wrong in the child process I spawn, but from what I see, if I call Read in non-blocking mode, so only after a PeekNamedPipe, there's nothing that prevent the process from being deallocated, even I keep a reference to the pipe.
I've solved launching another thread that does blocking Read on the pipe descriptor, and I'm longer loosing the last bytes..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not there.

You do have some problems in your code. Many are minors : you initialize twice si2 and pi2 (harmless), you have an endless loop so your prog will never end (I assume you Ctrl-C ...), you are mixing `_tmain` and WCHAR (should be either `wmain` and `WCHAR` or `_tmain` and `TCHAR`) but if you do an unicode build it is fine.

One is more serious : `chBuf` has size `BUFSIZE`, you read upto `BUFSIZE` chars in it (fine till here). But if you do read BUFSIZE chars, `dwRead` is `BUFSIZE` and on next line you have a buffer overflow

```
chBuf[dwRead] = 0; // buffer overflow if BUFSIZE chars have been read !
```

I only fixed that with :

```
if (!ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd2, chBuf, BUFSIZE - 1, &dwRead, NULL))
```

and the program works correctly.

BTW : the child process is knows by the system (even if terminated) until all handles to it have been closed ... and you have a handle to it in `pi2.hProcess`.

Of course I could not use `c:\\myprocess.exe` and tested with `cmd /c dir`. So if the above fix is not enough try to use same child as I did because the problem could come from `myprocess.exe` that is started with a NULL hStdInput

Comment: that was a test code i used to replicate and post there, production code is somewhat different. This does not change the fact that sleeping and not fetching the last bytes fastly, does not capture the output.I'm start to think the problem is with the child process that's out of my control..

Comment: @LeonardoBernardini : Hans Passant's comment maybe more explicit than what I wrote, but I agree with both of you : IMHO the problem is in child process since I could not reproduce with `cmd /dir`. But you could alse try to create a second pipe (for `hStdInput`) so that your child process could read on stdin without errors.